# Create APK file in React Native in Release mode

Tags: react-native

When I am creating react native project there is no android file in my project then how do I create apk file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMCiZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must generate a private key by running

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore servento.keystore -alias servento-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Then you have to set the generated file `my-release-key.keystore` under android/app in your project.
Edit the file `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` as following

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=[YOUR PASSWORD]
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=[YOUR PASSWORD]
Now edit android/app/build.gradle as following:

  signingConfigs {
        release {            
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

And in your terminal run `cd android` && `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`
Your APK will be generated inside this directory android/app/build/outputs/apk/ as `app-release.apk`

Comment: your answer works for react-native-cli where u have separate android and ios folders. here, he is using expo, so this answer doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

you are using expo cli for this project. to make an apk, you can use the old `expo build:android` or the new eas build. Here's the documentation for `expo build:android` method: https://docs.expo.dev/classic/building-standalone-apps/

here's the docs for the eas build: https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/

you can choose between either of the builds, but personally i prefer the older `expo build:android`

Comment: Can i create react project in any other way..

Comment: right now you must have done expo init, the other way to do that is with react-native cli. the full docs are here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup